# GraphViz gui crashing on rendering

Tags: charts, graphviz

I have a .dot/.gv file that is a DirectedGraph with about 55,000 edges.  When I try to render it using the GraphViz GUI in OsX it just sits a `Not Responding` state in Activity Monitor.  I would assume that GraphViz wouldn't have any problems rendering a graph of this size.  But it always crashes.

I know the .dot notation is valid because when I run: `dot test.gv -Tjpeg -o test.jpeg` it presumably draws something, I can't see it, but it at least it doesn't error out.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sfdp is the answer I was looking for.